# Color-code plotly bars fill and border by factors

Tags: r, colors, border, bar-chart, plotly

I'm trying to produce a bar chart using `R`'s `plotly` for these data:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c(paste0("B.",1:3),paste0("C.",1:3)),
                 x = 0:5, y = 0.2, width = 0.75,
                 group = c(rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),
                 class = c(rep("P",2),rep("X",2),rep("P",2)),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

As you can see each `name` in `df` is associated with a `group` and a `class`.

I would like the bar fill colors for `class` `P` to obey their `group` and for `class` `X` to be transparent (or gray), but have the border colors of both `class` `X` and `P` to obey their `group`.

Here's how I'm producing the plot so far, only coloring by `group`:

```
df$group <- factor(df$group)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

plotly::plot_ly(df,showlegend=T) %>%
  plotly::add_bars(x=~x,y=~y,width=~width,color=~group) %>%
  plotly::layout(legend=list(x=1,y=0)) %>%
  plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title=NA,zeroline=F,tickangle=45,range=x.range,tickvals=df$x,ticktext=df$name),yaxis=list(title=NA,zeroline=F,showgrid=F,range=c(0,1),showticklabels=F))
```

Which gives:
[image]

Any idea?